# Comparing HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, comparison, hashmap

I have two HashMaps: FOO & BAR.

HashMap FOO is a superset of HashMap BAR.

How do I find out what 'keys' are missing in HashMap BAR (i.e. exists in FOO but not BAR)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) (and realistically I think it should be on the classpath of more or less every non-trivial Java project) it's just:

```
Set<X> missing = Sets.difference(foo.keySet(), bar.keySet();
```

Comment: You can also use `MapDifference<Key, Value> mapDiff = Maps.difference(FOO, BAR);` and examine the resulting object for a full description of how the maps differ.

Comment: Oh wow. Haven't looked at MapDifference before, thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 13):

```
Set missing = new HashSet(foo.keySet());
missing.removeAll(bar.keySet());
```

Comment: +1 for making a new set.  foo.keySet().removeAll() will actually modify the foo map.